# ElasticSearch aggregation from a given array of values

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to aggregate from a given array having ids in one query. The explaination is as follows-

I have an array having sku ids like

```
array(
   [0] => 34,
   [1] => 67, 
   [2] => 12
)
```

I have a orders index in which orders.sku_id is present as

```
"_index":"orders",
"_type":"orders",
"_id":"249622367",
"_score":1,
"_source":{  
   "Order":{  
      "id":"249622367",
      "sku.id":34,
      "gross_value":"310",
      "quantity":"1"
   }
},
"_index":"orders",
"_type":"orders",
"_id":"249622364",
"_score":1,
"_source":{  
   "Order":{  
      "id":"249622364",
      "sku.id":34,
      "gross_value":"510",
      "quantity":"2"
   }
},
"_index":"orders",
"_type":"orders",
"_id":"249622365",
"_score":1,
"_source":{  
   "Order":{  
      "id":"249622365",
      "sku.id":67,
      "gross_value":"560",
      "quantity":"2"
   }
}
```

I want aggregation on gross_value and quantity having sku_id(from sku_ids array) as the histogram and desired output is as follows-

```
"aggregations": {
      "skus": {
         "buckets": [
            {
                "sku_id": 34,
                "gross_value": "820",
                "quantity": "3"
            },
            {
                "sku_id": 67,
                "gross_value": "560",
                "quantity": "2"
             },
             {
                 "sku_id": 12,
                 "gross_value": 0,
                 "quantity": 0
              }
           ]
       }
  }
```

I tried terms aggregation on sku_id and sum aggregation on gross_value & quantity, but couldn't get through.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.